# Identical feature on two devices but different behaviors/scenarios for BDD testing

Tags: testing, bdd, gherkin

The feature : As a user, I want to be able to change the anniversary of a panda

We have two versions of our app : Desktop / Mobile

On desktop we have to go to the detail page of a panda -> we click to the change anniversary date button -> pop up where we can enter the new date, we validate and it's done. It gives this scenario :

```
Given the user is in the detail page of a panda    
and the user is logged  
When the user update the anniversary date of the panda  
Then the anniversary date is updated
```

On mobile we have to select the menu change anniversary date -> new page where we enter a panda name  -> we are send to a new page where we enter the new anniversary date. We validate and it's done. It gives this scenario :

```
Given the user is in the Change Anniversary mode  
And a panda is selected  
And the user is logged  
When the user update the anniversary date  
Then the anniversary date is updated.
```

If I found easy to write scenarios for the desktop, for the mobile I'm blocked on the possible scenario to select a non existing panda. This behavior can't exist on the desktop since we have a list of panda and we have to click on one to go to the detail page. Instead of that, on mobile we have to enter the name of a panda so it's possible we enter a non existent name. I have for the moment this scenario but I don't like it :

```
Given the user is in the Change Anniversary mode  
And the user is logged  
When the user enter a non existing panda name  
Then an error message is shown
```

&

```
Given the user is in the Change Anniversary mode  
And the user is logged  
When the user enter an existing panda name  
Then the panda is selected
```

And I'm blocked because the new feature offered is identical on both device. Do I need to make my behaviors/scenarios match between Desktop and Mobile or is it okay that my behaviors/scenarios are a different based on the platform ? If I choose the second option How do I precise the platform : on the title scenario or in the Given ? What about all others scenarios I already written ? I hope someone already find a solution for this problem :p

Thank you for your help !

EDIT : I added the title feature and some scenarios I have for the moment :)

Comment: Can you add some scenarios to your question so we can see what you mean? I'm split between writing different scenarios or rephrasing your steps so they apply to each platform. We do not have enough information to answer your question.

Comment: I added feature title and some of my scenarios, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are not very clear, you say `On desktop we have to go to the detail page of a panda -> we click to the change anniversary date button -> pop up where we can enter the new date, we validate and it's done. It gives this scenario` but in the scenario you mention that the user is logged and i don't see where this happens, before needing to select a panda or after.

Just from what I could understand, you have 2 options:

1. have different scenarios for mobile and desktop, you can annotate with a platform tag e.g. @mobile and based on this tab to open the specific platform, or just create different suites, one for mobile(if you have native application) and one for desktop
2. don't add specific platform details and handle the details in the implementation

```
Given I am logged in
When I change the anniversary date for a panda
Then the anniversary date is changed
```

What I recommend: If there are just few differences you can use the second option, but it you have a lot of them then maybe it's better to have different scenarios for mobile and desktop, also if you have native app then I would say to execute them in different suites

Comment: HI ! Thanks for your answer ^^ In fact we do have a lot of different scenarios for the mobile app. It's not a native one, but since it will be used  by different users and in a different way than the Desktop app, I'm agree that we need to separate our tests. I didn't mention the logged in because it's in the background, like we can't do anything beside logged in in the desktop or mobile app so I don't put it in each Given, in the bakcground and it's effective for all others scenarios ^^

Answer (score 0):

Since my behaviors are different and my users are different for the mobile and desktop app I decided to separate my scenario and like lauda said, it gives me the ability to use a different solution to test if it was a native mobile app (not in my case now but for others ^^).

In my project, mobile and desktop scenarios are separate in different files :

../features/anniversary_panda/desktop/

```
Background: Login
Given the user is logged in as a panda manager

Scenario: Change anniversary date for a panda
Given the user is in the detail page of a panda    
When the user update the anniversary date of the panda
Then the anniversary date is updated
```

../features/anniversary_panda/mobile/

```
Background: Login
Given the user is logged in as a veterinary

Scenario: Change anniversary date for a panda
Given the user is in the Change Anniversary mode  
And a new date is already entered
When the user enter an existing panda name  
Then the anniversary date is updated
```

Thanks for your help, just explaining my case to you helps me a lot :)